# How do I connect to Azure Analysis Services with a username and password. Not with AD

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

It's not clear to me how to connect to Azure Analysis Services with a username and password not with an AD user.

Can I create a user for Azure Analysis Services?

In the UI I see a "connection strings" button. I have not found documentation on what this is.
[image]

Is this where I can define and save a username and password for users to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding AAS is tightly coupled with Azure AD and unlike Azure db wherein you have SQL aacount,AAS doesnt support it.
similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/812676/sql-auth-for-aas.html

Comment: I played with it more and it appears "username" and "password" refers to your azure/ad username and password. I thought it was a separate user account you could create for analysis services specifically. Love to confirm this though because docs are very unclear to me.

Comment: Hey, as stated the username and pwd are your AD account username and creds. Not an account independent of AD